# DateToArray is not defined in couchbase sync gateway

Tags: view, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I write the code for couchbase view. follow this https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys/

```
const mapDate = `function(doc, meta) {
  emit(dateToArray(doc.updatedAt), {
     _id: meta.id,
     _rev: meta.rev,
     updatedAt: doc.updatedAt
  });
}`
```

and when I call [http://localhost:4984/{db}/_design/{ddoc}/_view/{view}](http://localhost:4984/%7Bdb%7D/_design/%7Bddoc%7D/_view/%7Bview%7D) I got an error

```
    Error running map function: ReferenceError: dateToArray is not defined
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqQ9A.png)

I use sync-gateway version 1.4
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog post you're referring to is about Couchbase Server, not Sync Gateway. So, it looks like `dateToArray` is not a pre-defined function available on Sync Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to query views via the Sync Gateway, you should be creating it through the [Sync Gateway REST interface](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/sync-gateway/admin-rest-api/index.html?v=1.4#/query/put__db___design__ddoc_). You cannot query for views directly created on Couchbase Server.

This [link](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/sync-gateway/views/index.html) should provide more insights into creating and querying views via Sync Gateway